# How to update progress bar

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm developing a simple loading screen for my application. I can only change the progress of my progress bar before calling stage.show() for it to show the updated value correctly.

I tried many threading solutions, including **Platform.runLater** and **Runnables**. I can see the progress value being updated in the logs, but the actual progress bar remains empty.

Main.java loads LoadingController first, and then CatalogScreenController.

```
public class LoadingController {

    @FXML
    public ProgressBar progressBar;
    private DoubleProperty progressUpdater;

    public void setPercentage(double percentage) {
        progressUpdater.set(percentage);
    }

    public void initialize(java.net.URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        progressUpdater = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
        progressBar.progressProperty().bind(progressUpdater);
    }
}
```

```
public class CatalogScreenController {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        for (Book book : books) {
            CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            new Thread(new LoadCatalogScreenRunnable(latch)).start();
            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            loadingController.setPercentage(loadingProgress) //loadingProgress is returned by the Runnable with a setter method

            // ..........
        }

        // ...........
    }

    // .............
}
```

I expected the UI to get updated every time a Runnable returned, but the progress bar stays empty instead (while the value of progressUpdater in LoadingController gets updated correctly). The only workaround i found is to call **stage.hide()** and then **stage.show()** right after loadingController.setPercentage(loadingProgress), but it makes the window all blinking and feels awfully wrong.

Comment: So, you're blocking your GUI thread with `latch.await()` and thus nullifying any benefit from using a background thread, and likely freezing the application. Why?

Comment: Well, if I remove the latch.await() my main thread will instantly try to update the UI after calling each thread. This will lead to my progress bar being updated x times before any of the secondary threads can change **loadingProgress**, thus the bar will stay at 0%.

Comment: Not if you update the code by using a callback mechanism. Look more closely at the duplicates to see how they handle this, and handle it they do.